How to open a motherboard .cad file?
I received a .cad file for my laptop's motherboard but don't know how to open it.
Any suggestion ?

Have you tried a web search?

Yep, I tried and also tried different design software, AutoCad and other similar software, but eventually it ran by boardviewer software. It's for motherboard's layout.

Welcome @R1S8K! Would you mind adding a self-answer with a description and a link to the software you found.  If you took a screenshot, that is always welcome too.  Thanks, and again, welcome!

Absolutely, that would be my pleasure.

After contacting the same person who provided me with .cad file. The software is boardviewer.
Can be downloaded from the official source:
https://boardviewer.net/
Here's another copy uploaded on google drive:
BoardViewer 1.9.zip

While you are allowed to answer your own questions, this appears to be spammy - to me.  The link is also unavailable, which could be because its blocked.  If you are the author of this, you are obliged to come clean.  Please read the help.

OK, I got you. When I added s to http it didn't open to me. But actually that's the official website. There's another one uploaded on google driver I will add it.
